# Adding OR condition it IF statement cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The following cmd is working fine for me

```
IF %var1% == value1 (
     echo true
) ELSE (
     echo false
)
```

What is the syntax for adding `OR`condition inside the `IF`?

for example:

```
IF %var1% == value1 OR %var1% == value2(
     echo true
) ELSE (
     echo false
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Introducing the easiest and ugliest method :

```
set bool=false

if %var1% == value1 set bool=true
if %var1% == value2 set bool=true

if %bool% == true (echo true) else (echo false)
```

I spent years with batch programming, but I don't find such `if.. or...` statement, but it do have "and" condition. Like so :

```
if %var1% == value1 if %var1% == value2 (echo all is true) else (echo all is false)
```

Comment: Sorry, the `and` version will echo *"all is false"* only if the first condition is evaluated to true and the second to false.

Comment: @MCND Because that's an "and" condition, it doesn't work like "or" condition

Comment: Yes, it is an `and`, but you only get the echo when the first condition is true. If both conditions are false (or only the first one) you don't get the message